# Present Perfect with "that"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect

I came across the sentence *"It's been thirty years since my parents first met."* I am sure that if I heard *"It's been thirty years **that** my parents first met"*, I would accept it as grammatical, but I can't find any reference to support this. Am I wrong?

Comment: "It's been thirty years **since** my parents first met" would be more likely, I suppose. Other than that, the sentence is right the way it is without **that**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to use present perfect on both sides for that sentence to work:

> It's been thirty years that my parents have been married.

Otherwise, remove the present perfect from the first part:

> It was thirty years ago that my parents first met.

In both examples, as well as the ones you referenced, *that* acts as a conjunction, or should. If you are trying to use it as a determiner, then it simply doesn't work there.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you would have to use the word *since*.

> It's been thirty years since my parents first met.

Using *since* here is actually related to the span of time since the moment your parents met, rather than the first half of the sentence. Using *that* would be grammatically incorrect. However, you could say:

> When I look back on my life, it's been thirty years that I wish I could forget.

In this instance, *that* is used to create a relative clause, connecting the thirty years to the last half of the sentence. You can do this with other things too:

> I have eaten something that wasn't good for me.

This isn't restricted to the present perfect, either:

> It's going to be thirty years that I wish I could forget.

But, as soon as you're talking about the span of time, you have to use *since* again.

> I have eaten at least three kilograms of cheese since my parents first met.
>
> I haven't eaten anything since yesterday.